# znode not created in zookeeper

Tags: connectivity

I use zookeeper and can't create znode .

```
[root@server-1 bin]# sh zkCli.sh  -server 127.0.0.1:2183
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2183
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2183(CONNECTED) 0] ls /
[zookeeper]
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2183(CONNECTED) 1] ls /zookeeper/quota
[]
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2183(CONNECTED) 2] ls
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2183(CONNECTED) 3] create /zookeeper/new
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2183(CONNECTED) 4] create /newnode
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2183(CONNECTED) 5] ls /
[zookeeper]
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2183(CONNECTED) 6]
```

Also, I want to create a new tag on this site. e.g Zookeeper. how can create new tag?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misunderstand `znodes`.

> Unlike is standard file systems, each node in a ZooKeeper namespace
>   can have data associated with it as well as children. It is like
>   having a file-system that allows a file to also be a directory.
>   (ZooKeeper was designed to store coordination data: status
>   information, configuration, location information, etc., so the data
>   stored at each node is usually small, in the byte to kilobyte range.)
>   We use the term znode to make it clear that we are talking about
>   ZooKeeper data nodes.

I used to use `zk-shell` to manage `Zookeeper` at all. `zk-shell` allows you to see the full tree of `znodes`. At the end of `README.md` you have an example with creating and managing `znodes`, including creation and removal process.

> ```
> (CONNECTED) /> create /source/znode1/znode11 'Hello' false false true
> (CONNECTED) /> create /source/znode2 'Hello' false false true
> (CONNECTED) /> create /target/znode1/znode12 'Hello' false false true
> (CONNECTED) /> create /target/znode3 'Hello' false false true
> (CONNECTED) /> tree
> .
> ├── target
> │   ├── znode3
> │   ├── znode1
> │   │   ├── znode12
> ├── source
> │   ├── znode2
> │   ├── znode1
> │   │   ├── znode11
> ├── zookeeper
> │   ├── config
> │   ├── quota
> (CONNECTED) /> mirror /source /target
> Are you sure you want to replace /target with /source? [y/n]:
> y
> Mirroring took 0.04 secs
> (CONNECTED) /> tree
> .
> ├── target
> │   ├── znode2
> │   ├── znode1
> │   │   ├── znode11
> ├── source
> │   ├── znode2
> │   ├── znode1
> │   │   ├── znode11
> ├── zookeeper
> │   ├── config
> │   ├── quota
> (CONNECTED) /> create /target/znode4 'Hello' false false true
> (CONNECTED) /> mirror /source /target false false true
> Mirroring took 0.03 secs
> (CONNECTED) />
> ```

Some time ago, I created a Docker image that allows you to build it and run easily, `docker-python3-zkshell`. Feel free to use it.

References:

- https://github.com/rgs1/zk_shell
- https://github.com/kamilzabielski/docker-python3-zkshell